# cast (int) does not work correctly

Tags: java, int, double

I initialized a double `a` with `Math.pow(10,24)`.
Now I need to convert double `a` to int `b`:

```
a = Math.pow(10,24)
int b = (int)a;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
```

System prints out :

```
1.0E24
2147483647
```

This result is obviously not correct.

Comment: Google "java integer overflow"

Comment: BigInteger is your friend, although even this won't be 100% accurate given double's limitations.

Comment: 10^24 is much too big to fit in an `int`.

Comment: [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) max value of an Integer is 10^31 -1 or am i wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It's because Integer has limit  INT_MAX - 2147483647

Comment: OK, but what is `INT_MAX`?  Where in Java is `INT_MAX` defined?

Comment: but why are INT_MAX and MAX_VALUE different?

Comment: you can read more about primitive data types like int here: [Click Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Primitive data type int, and [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class is different.